# C# Entityframework core error executing raw sqlstring with more parameter values

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am trying to build a SqlQuery at runtime and trying to execute the `_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync()` but getting the following error. There are around 620 rows to be inserted with total number of parameter values around 4400. Not sure how to handle this. Can anyone help me how to solve this.

code:

var sqlSb = new StringBuilder();

```
    sqlSb.AppendLine("INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserTag](UserId, TagId, Disabled, Created, CreatedBy, Modified, ModifiedBy)");
    sqlSb.AppendLine("VALUES");
    
    var index = 0;
    var noOfcolumnsToInsert = 7;
    var query = new SqlQuery();
    
    foreach (var userTag in userTags)
    {
        var countFrom = index * noOfcolumnsToInsert;
        index++;

        sqlSb.AppendLine($"({{{countFrom}}}, {{{countFrom + 1}}}, {{{countFrom + 2}}}, {{{countFrom + 3}}}, {{{countFrom + 4}}}, {{{countFrom + 5}}}, {{{countFrom + 6}}}){(index < userTags.Count ? "," : "")}");
        query.ParameterValues.AddRange(new List<object> { userTag.UserId, userTag.TagId, userTag.Disabled, currentDateTime, sessionUserGuidAsString, currentDateTime, sessionUserGuidAsString });
    }

    query.Sql = sqlSb.ToString();

    await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(query.Sql, query.ParameterValues.ToArray());
```

SqlQuery class:

```
public class SqlQuery
{
    public string Sql { get; set; }
    public List<object> ParameterValues { get; set; }

    public SqlQuery()
    {
        ParameterValues = new List<object>();
    }
}
```

Error:

> The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request

Comment: why not use a SP and a table valued parameter?

Comment: If you are trying to make `BulkCopy` it is not good way. EF should create the same SQL but with overhead that it may fetch identity values back. And yes there is limitation how many parameters can be passed - 2100 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes the limit shows is 2200. So what is the best way to solve this? As J.Salas  mentioned do i need to use a SP and a table valued parameter?

Comment: I would suggest to use extensions which make this process easy [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) - I'm one of the creators and you can search for others. Or split big query into chunks, or yes use DataTable as parameter for stored procedure.